# Processing this item failed because of a IFilter parser error

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, crawl, index-component

Sp2013 Standard Server.

Search Type: continuous Crawl

Search Content Source: Local SharePoint Site

Configuration DB Version:15.0.4551.1001

```
Processing this item failed because of a IFilter parser error. ( Error parsing document 'https://Siteurl/Shift Log 07-09-2014.xlsx'. Error loading IFilter for extension '.zip' (Error code is 0x80CB4204). The function encountered an unknown error.; ; SearchID = 8FCAAFF3-986F-4172-9DBC-C3DFE1110AAD )
```

Same Error Applies for File type .vsd .zip.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is click on the link to the document and see if it can be loaded. If the document is not corrupt, start up Excel (or whatever client app is involved) as your search account i.e. runas...sp-crawling-account-whateverthatmaybe and see if that account can still open the file and read it.

If these two things are OK then I would expect that you have trouble parsing that type of file in general and you probably have lots and lots of errors relating to that. In that case you will want to go deeper into how to re-register your IFilter for that file type.